# Solidworks Loft error (guide curve not intersecting with profiles)

Tags: modeling, cad, solidworks

I am trying to add 'finger grooves' to my model of a brake lever and want to use a loft to do so. I have created (to my knowledge) all required sketches for the loft but **SW gives me an error when trying to select a guide curve**... (please see image below), which is strange since I drew the sketches such that the edges of the profiles should intersect with the guide curves... I am not sure what I am doing wrong...(I get a similar error when I try to select the other guide curve instead)

**The error:**
[image]

**The file:** https://forum.solidworks.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/244266-1-225417/Saint+lever+extended+5.SLDPRT.zip

Another weird thing which (I think) is causing some issues with creating the guide curve (the one highlighted in blue) properly: There is a transition at a certain point in the model where I applied a fillet to round off the lever surface, before applying the fillet there was no transition after there was... very weird.. please take a look at the image below.
[image]

I made a very simple drawing (see image below) of the part (before adding the aforementioned fillet), I've dimensioned the 'curvy' bits to try to make the shape (which parts are straight lines) clearer.
[image]

Would you know of a way to get rid of said transition (and what may be causing it)? Would it be possible to get rid of the transition whilst still using the fillet feature for the rounding of the handle? Or would I have to use a swept cut instead of a fillet to eliminate this transition? Is there a way to create the desired 'finger cavities' without getting rid of the transition?

The result of the loft should look somewhat similar to the image below (but the shape will be repeated more times/and will be slightly more 'rounded' than the shape seen in the picture)

[image]

I have added the file as an attachment

**Any input is greatly appreciated, thank you very much!**

Comment: seeing the file would be really useful - I don’t see any attachment. How about a link using e.g. Dropbox or filedropper.com?

Comment: For your first issue, the guide curve appears to be disjointed - try using fit spline to make it into one continuous entity, and then using pierce constraints on the profiles.

Comment: Your second issue needs the file to diagnose, really. You could try face fillets rather than edge selection.

Comment: Hi @Marteen -Monica for president , - unfortunately the file that you uploaded there doesn't match the images in your question - it doesn't have the problematic sketches or fillet. It looks more like the final reference image of the Straitline lever: https://i.imgur.com/U6dl6fO.png

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Sorry, uploaded wrong file.... here is the correct file: https://forum.solidworks.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/244266-1-225417/Saint+lever+extended+5.SLDPRT.zip (also updated link in my original post)